# I have built the commands by using docker and the output is successsful and I am unable to open the localhost 7604

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ubuntu, docker

** These are the commands which i have used**

1.$ sudo docker build -t="prabakar/java7" .

Sending build context to Docker daemon 4.608 kB

Sending build context to Docker daemon

Step 0 : FROM ubuntu:saucy

---> 195eb90b5349

Step 1 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

---> Using cache

---> 4f1ffd94ad85

Step 2 : RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common

---> Using cache

---> 1d972cf31614

Step 3 : RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

---> Using cache

---> a479b931080e

Step 4 : RUN apt-get -y update

---> Using cache

---> 4953b8e1e1b2

Step 5 : RUN echo "oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 boolean true" | debconf-set-selections

---> Using cache

---> 074e0bcc47f7

Step 6 : RUN apt-get -y install oracle-java7-installer

---> Using cache

---> 5de174a53567

Step 7 : RUN apt-get -y install tomcat7

---> Using cache

---> fbaf2c3b594b

Step 8 : RUN echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle" >> /etc/default/tomcat7

---> Using cache

---> d75cc6e4d41f

Step 9 : EXPOSE 7604

---> Using cache

---> e28931a42d90

Step 10 : RUN mkdir /var/lib/tomcat-7.0-doc

---> Running in a07cc29cd8bb

---> 029a57ec552a

Removing intermediate container a07cc29cd8bb

Step 11 : RUN wget http://tomcat.apache.org/ -P /var/lib/tomcat-7.0-doc

---> Running in b5b9a1c271c4

--2014-12-22 07:26:40--  http://tomcat.apache.org/

Resolving tomcat.apache.org (tomcat.apache.org)... 54.172.167.43, 192.87.106.229, 2001:610:1:80bc:192:87:106:229

Connecting to tomcat.apache.org (tomcat.apache.org)|54.172.167.43|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

Length: 11540 (11K) [text/html]

Saving to: '/var/lib/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html'

```
 0K .......... .                                          100%  140M=0s
```

2014-12-22 07:26:41 (140 MB/s) - '/var/lib/tomcat-7.0-doc/index.html' saved [11540/11540]

---> c5edb92f2f31

Removing intermediate container b5b9a1c271c4

Successfully built c5edb92f2f31

2. $ sudo docker run -i -t prabakar/java7 /bin/bash

root@6b635fc414c5:/# exit

3. $ sudo docker ps -l

CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                  COMMAND         CREATED           STATUS    PORTS  NAMES

6b635fc414c5 prabakar/java7   "/bin/bash"      25 seconds ago           Exited

Comment: it would be better to format your commands and output using markdown

Answer (score 0):

You are running bin/bash in the docker. When that runs, you type 'exit', so bash terminates, and then the docker terminates, as can be seen in the docker ps command. Try leaving that window open after you run

```
sudo docker run -i -t prabakar/java7 /bin/bash
```

and then connect to port 7604.

A better solution would be to make your docker run tomcat as its main command. Try:

```
sudo docker run -i -t prabakar/java7 "tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run"
```

You may need to disable tomcat autorun on startup for this to work (apt-get probably starts the service automatically).

Comment: If i use the command                                                                     sudo docker run -i -t prabakar/java7 /bin/bash also i am unable to connect the port 7604 .

Comment: inside the docker, check that tomcat is running, and listening on the port you are expecting it.